# WCF service file access through stream

Tags: stream, wcf-data-services

I am currently working on a project where I need to access a file through a wcf service. I was wondering if it is possible to get a stream object to a remote file? The way I am picturing it working is the server opens the file and returns the stream object to the client. Then the client can access it just like any other stream object but everything is done across the network. Is there anything like this in place?

I saw some stuff that looked like you could do this but I couldn't find much. I tried returning a Stream but it seems like the client gets a byte[]. It seems like in this case it would just read and return the whole file which wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand WCF runs on the HTTP protocol and hence is unable to stream files, at least in the way that a true client/server setup might.